# Terraform: Security group to connect an ASG to an ALB

Tags: load-balancing, terraform, vpc

## My settings

I am building a pretty standard stack of an Auto Scale group of EC2 instances, receiving traffic via an ALB.

The instances expose port 80 to the entire VPC, and the ALB exposes port 443 with a certificate externally to receive traffic from the Internet.

## My problem

I would like enable port 80 access from the ALB only, not from the entire VPC.

## My question

How can I define a security group in Terraform, that exposes port 80 of the instances to the ALB only, but not to other parts of the VPC?

Comment: You can reference other security group ids in ingress rules https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html#security_groups, so: attach SG1 to ALB; in SG2 add rule to allow 80 from SG1; attach SG2 to launch config

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "opened_to_alb" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 80
  to_port                  = 80
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = "${var.alb_sg_id}"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.your_sg.id}"
}
```

var.alb_sg_id can be replaced with your actual alb security group id.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a security group (aws_security_group) for your load balancer and give that access to port 80 using an aws_security_group_rule.

Then, in the security group of the servers, you want to only have allow access to them from for port 80 only from the load balancer security group like so `source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.mylb.id}"`

Does this make sense? If not, I can elaborate further.